# Browser stops reading PHP after greater than (>) symbol. Running from FTP Server

Tags: php, sql, browser

Firefox is not interpreting PHP code at all.

I have already tried activating PHP via terminal (I am on a mac). I have tried a total of 5 different browsers. Chrome, Brave, and Opera simply downloads the PHP file, Safari is weird about FTP and Firefox has the problem explained below. I have tried replacing all instances of ">" with >. All files have a .php extension and are in the same folder.

Viewing a simple PHP file on an FTP server, Firefox either displays a blank page with PHP code such as:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

or stops at the greater than sign (>) in code such as:

```
<?php
echo "<P>Hello World!</P>";
?>
```

In the above instance, the browser displays, in plain text:

```
Hello World!

"; ?>
```

This is not the code I am using, obviously, but my more complex code is having the same problem - namely not working at all or stopping at the greater than sign.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Full Disclosure: I am very much a beginner at this.

Comment: Do you have a web server (Apache/Nginx/etc.) installed on your machine? Web browser does not execute PHP file, it's the job of the web server.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that your web server is not properly configured. What you see is a text and your browser tries to show to you as a plain HTML (or even download it as a file). Your web server "believes" that this file is a plain text and you get it as is without any modification by PHP.

You should configure your web server (usually, PHP + Apache/Nginx) to execute `.php` files. I also highly recommend you play with `<?php phpinfo();` instead of `<?php echo 'Hello World';` to understand that PHP is able to launch `.php` files.

More detailed answer about the server configuration can be found in the Google by the search request "Mac LAMP" or "Mac LEMP" depends on your desired web server (A = Apache, E = nginx).

Comment: Thank you for your responses. I have activated apache via mac terminal. localhost tells me "it works!" but still no progress. I will also take your advice and use the phpinfo to check this. I used an http:// host for an old php file I made and it worked directly on the browser. Does the ftp:// address have anything to do with it?

Comment: @RyanPHPConfusion, `ftp://` protocol is not for web browsing. Short answer is - try XAMPP or similar product which preconfigure web-server for you in a few clicks. Long answer - find a proper documentation for your OS with all steps from php/apache/mysql installation to apache configuration. It's hard to tell what's wrong with your server mainly because no one know what you've done and which steps skipped.